# Проблема с написанием скрипта для (не своего) сайта.

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, консоль

Не знаю, как лучше сформулировать вопрос, поэтому постараюсь объяснить на деле:
нужно сделать скрипт, который в последствии будет автоматически заменять сжатую версию картинки HD версией. Для большинства интернет ресурсов это было сделать не сложно, даже с моим практически отсутствующим навыком программирования, но при попытке сделать такой скрипт для сайта DeviantArt, я мучаюсь уже несколько дней. То при сочетании "сначала открыть вкладку с картинкой, у которой нету HD версии, затем на той же вкладки открыть другую картинку с HD" возникали баги и ошибки, исправление которых уже раз 4 заставляло переписывать код по новой. То просто кретинизм, наступающий в результате отсутствии краткости таланта при написании кода. Картинку с кодом, приложу просто для осведомления, но вопрос заключается не совсем по моему коду.
[image: somebody help me pls]

Все мои проблемы с написанием этого кода возникли из-за особенности то ли конкретно DeviantArt, то ли из-за просто слишком малого опыта. Дело в том, что картинка (`document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-normal")`) может находиться либо в `[0]`, либо в `[1]`. При открытии абсолютно новой вкладки, она будет находиться по адресу `document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-normal")[0]`, при открытии следующей картинке, уже по `[1]`. Если с этим всё ещё не слишком сложно, то в случаи с адресом, по которому располагается HD версия, всё сложнее [image: .]

Сложнее всё потому, что в зависимости от того, какую я открываю первую вкладку - с картинкой, у которой есть HD версия, или у которой её нету - появляется несколько вариантов комбинации. 
Были попытки и сбрасывать страницу через `window.location.reload()` и делать кучу проверок, но, вероятно, из-за владения малым количеством команд, которыми я пользуюсь, все варианты комбинаций пофиксить не получалось и в результате при какой-то комбинации возникал либо графический баг, либо бесконечный спам в консоли текстом типажа `TypeError: Cannot read property 'href' of undefined`. А после нужды добавить проверку формата контента, при котором код бы не работал на "не картинки", эффект с количеством возможных комбинаций и вытекающих из них ошибок увеличился просто до непосильных мне размеров. Мой вопрос по сути заключается в том, как мне избавится от сложности со всеми этими комбинациями, к примеру, за счёт исключения появления `[1]`.

Я понимаю, что мои запросы скорее актуальны для сайтов с фрилансом, и просто беспокоить мне излишне своей проблемой никого не хотелось, но уже столько времени и сил на эту цель потрачено, что может, больше успехов будет, если мне помогут знающие люди.

Прошу прощение за такие излишние подробности и замудрённости, вероятно, в связи с этими постоянными безуспешными попытками просто наступила умственная усталость.

Comment: поменьше используйте интервалы, еще и интервалы в интервалах, зачем их так много то? у вас там код сплошной зацикленый интервал, не удивительно что вас там заваливает ошибками

Answer (score 0):

По первой части - про разные ключи в массиве, ну на сайте просто два элемента текущий и предыдущий, что бы не думать об этом, просто всегда берите последний элемент:

```
var arrImages = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-normal");
var image = arrImages[arrImages.length-1];
console.log(image.src)
```

Теперь при первом открытии у вас в массиве будет всего один элемент по ключу 0, и вы его получите (он один он последний), когда дальше перейдете, у вас в массиве элементов будет два значения, и текущий по ключу 1 (и он же последний).

По второй части - после получения тега изображения, получаете id и ищите кнопку для скачивания:

```
var arrImages = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-normal");
var image = arrImages[arrImages.length-1];

var id = image.getAttribute('data-embed-id');
var download = document.querySelector('.dev-page-download[data-deviationid="'+id+'"]');
console.log(download.href);
```

Answer (score 0):

(Вопрос был опубликован при отсутствии аккаунта, за счёт указания почты. По итогу, конечная регистрация по ссылке, пришедшей на почту, создала новый аккаунт (этот), по-скольку на "старый" зайти теперь невозможно, отпишу с этого)

Хотелось бы от всей души поблагодарить Bookin, помощь действительно оказалась существенной и помогла решить мою проблему. Искреннее спасибо!

Пока что проблем при выполнении кода обнаружено не было, получился код в итоге такой:

```
window.onload=function(){
var arrImages = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-normal");
var image = arrImages[arrImages.length-1];
var arrImagesFull = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-full");
var imageFull = arrImagesFull[arrImagesFull.length-1];
    if(image == null) {
    } else {
    var id = image.getAttribute('data-embed-id');
    }
var download = document.querySelector('.dev-page-download[data-deviationid="'+id+'"]');
    if(download == null) {
    var format = download;
    } else {
    var format = download.href.split(".").pop().split("?")[0];
    }
};
    setInterval(function (){
    arrImages = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-normal");
    image = arrImages[arrImages.length-1];
    arrImagesFull = document.getElementsByClassName("dev-content-full");
    imageFull = arrImagesFull[arrImagesFull.length-1];
        if(image == null) {
        } else {
        var id = image.getAttribute('data-embed-id');
        }
    download = document.querySelector('.dev-page-download[data-deviationid="'+id+'"]');
        if(download == null) {
        format = download;
        } else {
        format = download.href.split(".").pop().split("?")[0];
        }
            if(format == "jpg" || format == "jpeg" || format == "png" || format == "gif" || format == "bmp" || format == "ico" || format == "tiff" || format == "jp2") {
                if(download == null) {
                    if(imageFull == null) {
                    } else {
                    image.src = imageFull.src;
                    }
                } else {
                image.src = download.href;
                    if(imageFull == null) {
                    } else {
                    imageFull.src = download.href;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(imageFull == null) {
                } else {
                image.src = imageFull.src;
                }
            }
    }, 500);
```